# Total bodegraph of 2 elementary fonction

Tags: bodegraph

did someone know how to plot the total transfer function on bodegraph??
I've managed to print correctly the firs two elementary function: `jwT` and `1/(1+jwT)`, but I can't find how to plot the total. The sum of this two bodegraph.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bodegraph} % per i diagrammi di Bode

\begin{document}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=7/4]
                [xscale=16.9/6]
                \begin{scope}[yscale=7/120]
                \tikzset{
                    semilog lines/.style={thin, black},
                    semilog lines 2/.style={semilog lines,
                        gray },
                    semilog half lines/.style={semilog lines 2,
                        dotted },
                    semilog label x/.style={semilog lines,
                        below,font=\tiny},
                    semilog label y/.style={semilog lines,
                        above right,font=\tiny}
                }

                \UnitedB
                \semilog{1}{7}{-60}{60}
                %% quella più sotto, sarà quella più visibile essendo sopra
                \BodeGraph[orange %thin
                ]{1:7}
                {-\POAmp{1}{0.00002209}}
                \BodeGraph[orange, thin]{1:7}
                {-\POAmpAsymp{1}{0.00002209}}
                \BodeGraph[LBlue1 %thin
                ]{1:6}
                {\POAmp{1}{0.00094}}
                \BodeGraph[LBlue1, thin]{1:6}
                {\POAmpAsymp{1}{0.00094}}
                \end{scope}
                \begin{scope}[yshift=-7cm,yscale=4/180]
                \tikzset{
                    semilog lines/.style={thin, black},
                    semilog lines 2/.style={semilog lines,
                        gray },
                    semilog half lines/.style={semilog lines 2,
                        dotted },
                    semilog label x/.style={semilog lines,
                        below,font=\tiny},
                    semilog label y/.style={semilog lines,
                        above right,font=\tiny}
                }
                \UniteDegre
                \OrdBode{30}
                \semilog{1}{7}{-90}{90}
                \BodeGraph[orange]{1:7}
                {-\POArg{1}{0.000022091}}
                \BodeGraph[%samples=2,
                LBlue1 ]
                {1:7}{\POArg{1}{0.00094}}

                \end{scope}
            \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Which give me this,[image], and its correct, but i need the "sum" of this 2 bode diagram.

Where do I start??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to sum the two plot commands in Bodegraph

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bodegraph} % per i diagrammi di Bode

\begin{document}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=7/4]
                [xscale=16.9/6]
                \begin{scope}[yscale=7/120]
                \tikzset{
                    semilog lines/.style={thin, black},
                    semilog lines 2/.style={semilog lines,
                        gray },
                    semilog half lines/.style={semilog lines 2,
                        dotted },
                    semilog label x/.style={semilog lines,
                        below,font=\tiny},
                    semilog label y/.style={semilog lines,
                        above right,font=\tiny}
                }

                \UnitedB
                \semilog{1}{7}{-60}{60}
                %% quella più sotto, sarà quella più visibile essendo sopra
                \BodeGraph[orange %thin
                ]{1:7}
                {-\POAmp{1}{0.000022091}}
                \BodeGraph[orange, thin]{1:7}
                {-\POAmpAsymp{1}{0.000022091}}
                \BodeGraph[blue %thin
                ]{1:6}
                {\POAmp{1}{0.00094}}
                \BodeGraph[blue, thin]{1:6}
                {\POAmpAsymp{1}{0.000941}}

            % faire la somme des deux courbes
            %do the sum of the two diagrams
                 \BodeGraph[red,thick %thin
                ]{1:7}
                {\POAmp{1}{0.00094}
                -\POAmp{1}{0.000022091}
                }                 
                 \BodeGraph[red, thin]{1:7}
                {\POAmpAsymp{1}{0.000941}
                -\POAmpAsymp{1}{0.000022091}
                }
                %==================

                \end{scope}
                \begin{scope}[yshift=-7cm,yscale=4/180]
                \tikzset{
                    semilog lines/.style={thin, black},
                    semilog lines 2/.style={semilog lines,
                        gray },
                    semilog half lines/.style={semilog lines 2,
                        dotted },
                    semilog label x/.style={semilog lines,
                        below,font=\tiny},
                    semilog label y/.style={semilog lines,
                        above right,font=\tiny}
                }
                \UniteDegre
                \OrdBode{30}
                \semilog{1}{7}{-90}{90}
                \BodeGraph[orange]{1:7}
                {-\POArg{1}{0.000022091}}
                \BodeGraph[%samples=2,
                blue]
                {1:7}{\POArg{1}{0.00094}}

            % faire la somme des deux courbes
            %do the sum of the two diagrams                
                 \BodeGraph[red,thick %thin
                ]{1:7}
                {\POArg{1}{0.00094}
                -\POArg{1}{0.000022091}
                }                 
                \end{scope}
            \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ohhh... It's that simple?? Thank you very much @rpapa

Comment: accept the answer